# Blazor Server routing case sensitivity

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, blazor-server-side

I have a BlazorServer application which has an api controller in it. The api controller has
`[Route("api/[controller]")]`
on it, and it works great if I access it at `/api/something` but I have a requirement for it to respond to `/api/Something`.

I have tried replacing the Route Attribute with `[Route("api/SomethingController")]` but, again it will only respond to `/api/something`

I would be fine if it only responds to `/api/Something` or if it's case insensitive.

How can I configure the routing to allow the `/api/Something` with the upper case S?

Answer (score 0):

Found it (minutes after posting the question)

```
builder.Services.AddRouting(ctx => ctx.LowercaseUrls = false);
```